# Can HKAnchoredObjectQuery query for a deleted HKSampleType in HealthKit?

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I have a HKObserverQuery set up that then uses a HKAnchoredObjectQuery to retrieve new additions for a HKSampleType. Is there any way to do the same thing for a HKSampleType that has been deleted? HKObserverQuery is called on a delete but there doesn't seem to be any way to figure out what was deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in iOS 9, you can use `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` to query HealthKit for deleted samples.  The use the new init method that takes a `resultsHandler` parameter.

Comment: Bummer. Not sure how to proceed with dealing with deletions then.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect changes to HealthKit in iOS 9, which make this possible.